# Интеграция форм с битрикс24 через API

Tags: crm, битрикс24

мне нужно мою форму передавать в CRM и создавать лидов, с помощью API но вместе с обычными полями нужно передавать UTM метку, кто делал такое, подскажите как правильно. Я так понимаю нужно создать пользовательские поля в битриксе и нужно просто в них записывать значение, у меня вопрос как получить доступ через API к пользовательским полям

Comment: чтобы информация о лидах передавалось в Битрикс, нужен Rest API, инструкция и сам файл тут [https://vk.cc/8ekaRp](https://vk.cc/8ekaRp) .
Что касается полей и что можно передавать написано в api битрикса